# In which version of Corda (open-source,Enterprise) is SGX technology implemented?

Tags: corda

We want to ascertain whether transaction data is protected from manipulation and all the transactions are secured, in Corda.

On reading the "Multilateral Ledger" topic in the notes given in the URL  https://www.corda.net/discover/technology.html, we learnt that Corda uses SGX technology that provides full encryption of transactions.

Shall we know in which version of Corda (open source or Enterprise) is it implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article in following link states that the SGX is a feature of Corda Enterprise -

https://docs.corda.net/design/sgx-infrastructure/design.html